# Mandrill template removing form elements

Tags: python, heroku, mandrill

I'm using the Python mandrill package 1.0.57, as a part of the mandrill add-on for my Heroku application. I attempt to add the following template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Test Title</title>

    <!-- TODO styles -->
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    {{#each projects}}
      <h3>{{this.name}}</h3>
      <form>
          <label for="log">Log</label>
          <input type="number" id="log" name="log">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
    {{/each}}
  </body>
</html>
```

The each loop and h3 work fine. However, I notice that upon adding the template, it has actually been **modified**. Specifically, the 'code' attribute of the template appears to be missing the form and input elements. The label is missing too, but its text, 'Log', is still present

This happens even if I place the elements outside of the loop. Are forms, inputs, and labels special?

Edit: I also directly tried a curl and it still modified my template.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @test.json https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/templates/add.json -v
```

Edit 2: I guess a working workaround is to just use messages.send()

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem?

Comment: Have the same issue